# сборка globalize-webpack-plugin под production

Tags: webpack

мой package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production&&webpack --progress",
    "dev": "SET NODE_ENV=development&&webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "cldr-data": "^30.0.4",
    "globalize": "^1.2.2",
    "globalize-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.10",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

мой webpack.config.js

```
'use strict';

var DEVELOPMENT = 'development';
var PRODUCTION = 'production';

var NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV === PRODUCTION ? PRODUCTION : DEVELOPMENT;

var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var GlobalizeWebpackPlugin = require('globalize-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.[hash].js',
        path: './dist'
    },

    watch: NODE_ENV === DEVELOPMENT,
    devtool: NODE_ENV === DEVELOPMENT ? 'inline-source-map' : false,

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js']
    },

    plugins: [
        new GlobalizeWebpackPlugin({
            production: NODE_ENV === PRODUCTION,
            developmentLocale: 'ru',
            supportedLocales: ['ru'],
            messages: "messages/[locale].json",
            output: "i18n/[locale].[hash].js"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'test',
            filename: 'index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

ну и app.js

```
var Globalize = require('globalize');
```

т.е. импортирую чисто globalize, в командной строке прописываю

```
npm run prod
```

собирается все гуд, но когда открываю html файл, выскакивает вот такая ошибка

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

т.е. модуль не найден.
когда собираю под development то все ок, работает.
подскажите в чем причина

Comment: там надо было vendor прописать в webpack.config.js
https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/blob/master/examples/app-npm-webpack/webpack-config.js